What thickness foam is best under vinyl siding?
I would like to increase the energy efficiency of my home so am replacing all windows and siding. I'd like to add a layer of rigid foam board between the wood sheeting and new vinyl siding. The house was built in 1958 and I am unsure of the R value of current insulation. The cost to heat my new home is significantly more than my old home of a larger size.
My contractor told me I could choose 1", 3/4", or 1/2" rigid foam board. He thinks 1" may be too much but ultimately it is up to me.
What thickness of rigid foam board would you recommend?

Is there a reason you aren't considering yet more foam?

Insulation is the right direction and the more the better. If you can get 1" polyisocyanurate, even better.
I assume that your attic insulation is up to current code. If not, that's an effective DIY project with good returns.
You don't mention if the project also includes wrapping the house with an air barrier.
The greatest increase in whole house comfort will be controlling air infiltration. If the wind continues to blow through the wall after the insulation is up, you are not getting full value from the insulation investment.
